# Is there any method to make the MaterialTable overflow scroll-able on x-axis?

Tags: material-ui

I am using MaterialTable from material-table package. I want the  the table to have scrollable on x-axis in order to deal with many columns. Below is the code:

```
<MaterialTable
    title="Members Account Logs"
    columns={columns}
    icons={tableIcons}
    data={data}
    options={{         
      headerStyle: 
      {           
        backgroundColor: 'black',           
        color: 'white'         
      },
      rowStyle:{
        backgroundColor: 'white',           
        color: 'black' 
      },
    }}
  />
```

What props should I pass to make the table scrollable on x-axis

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to wrap the  into the div with style as:

```
<div 
  style={{
    width:'1535px',
    overflowX:'auto'
   }}
>
  <MaterialTable
    title="Members Account Logs"
    columns={columns}
    icons={tableIcons}
    data={data}
    options={{         
      headerStyle: 
      {           
        backgroundColor: 'black',           
        color: 'white'         
      },
      rowStyle:{
        backgroundColor: 'white',           
        color: 'black' ,
      },
      padding: "dense",
      tableLayout: "block",
      overflowX:"auto"
     
    }}
  />
</div>
```

The div makes the boundaries limit for the page and hence the MaterialTable will have overflow on x-axis